# Splitter group attribute inject variable parameter

Tags: apache, apache-camel

can you inject a value from the config params file in to the splitter group attribute? if so, what is the proper way of doing it?  thanks!

I've tried,

```
<split streaming="true" >
<tokenize token="\n" group="{{noOfLines}}" />
<log message="Split Group Body: ${body}"/>
    <to uri="bean:extractHeader" />
    <to id="acceptedFileType" ref="pConsumer" /> 
</split>

<split streaming="true" >
<tokenize token="\n" group={{noOfLines}} />
<log message="Split Group Body: ${body}"/>
    <to uri="bean:extractHeader" />
    <to id="acceptedFileType" ref="pConsumer" /> 
</split>
```

what am I doing wrong?

```
ERROR:  'Open quote is expected for attribute "group" associated with an  element type  "tokenize".

<tokenize token="\n" group="<simple>${properties:noOfLines:500}</simple>" /> 
ERROR:  'The value of attribute "group" associated with an element type "tokenize" must not contain the '<' character.'

            <tokenize token="\n" group="${properties:noOfLines:500}" /> 

Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-datatype-valid.1.2.1: '${properties:noOfLines:500}' is not a valid value for 'integer'.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my quest for info and answers didn't go deep enough. I found this was already encounted and answered by Claus Ibsen. Please see if you run in to this need.

[Validation error with integer property (camel)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27859466/validation-error-with-integer-property-camel)

http://camel.apache.org/using-propertyplaceholder.html

under section "Using Property Placeholders for Any Kind of Attribute in the XML DSL"

here is what I did following these instructions.

added property prefix namespace
      xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"

then modified the tokenize attribute

```
<tokenize token="\n" prop:group="noOfLines" />
```

I'm using the property placeholder

```
<cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.digital.passthru.core" />
```

this works like a charm.  thank you Claus.

Comment: Hey there, I'm trying to achieve the same thing but importing the xmlns can't resolve the uri `xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"` can't resolve... any idea what's wrong?

Comment: Im facing the same issue but with Java DSL. any suggestion please ?

Answer (score 0):

this is what worked for me.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <blueprint
      xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xmlns:prop="http://camel.apache.org/schema/placeholder"
      xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
      xmlns:cm="http://aries.apache.org/blueprint/xmlns/blueprint-cm/v1.0.0"
      xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint 
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd">

    <cm:property-placeholder persistent-id="com.ge.digital.passthru.core" />

    <bean id="deadLetterErrorHandler" class="org.apache.camel.builder.DeadLetterChannelBuilder">
        <property name="deadLetterUri" value="${deadLetterQueue}"/>
        <property name="redeliveryPolicy" ref="redeliveryPolicyConfig"/>
        <property name="useOriginalMessage" value="true" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="redeliveryPolicyConfig" class="org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryPolicy">
        <property name="maximumRedeliveries" value="3"/>
        <property name="redeliveryDelay" value="5000" />

    </bean>
```

...

```
<camelContext     
  id="com.ge.digital.passthru.coreCamelContext"
  trace="true"
  xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
  allowUseOriginalMessage="false"
  streamCache="true"
  errorHandlerRef="deadLetterErrorHandler" >
```

...

```
<route 
    id="core.predix.accept.file.type.route"
    autoStartup="true" >
    <from uri="{{fileEntranceEndpoint}}" />
    <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" />
    <split streaming="true" strategyRef="csvAggregationStrategy">
    <tokenize token="\n" />
      <process ref="toCsvFormat" />     <!-- passthru only we do not allow embedded commas in numeric data -->
    </split>
    <log message="CSV body: ${body}" loggingLevel="INFO"/>
    <choice>
        <when>
            <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*\.(csv|CSV|txt|gpg)$'</simple>
            <log message="${file:name} accepted for processing..." />
            <choice>
              <when>
                <simple>${header.CamelFileName} regex '^.*\.(CSV|txt|gpg)$'</simple>
                <setHeader headerName="CamelFileName">
            <!--    <simple>${file:name.noext}.csv</simple> -->  <!-- file:name.noext.single -->
                    <simple>${file:name.noext.single}.csv</simple>
                </setHeader>
                <log message="${file:name} changed file name." />                   
              </when>
            </choice>
            <split streaming="true" >
            <tokenize token="\n" prop:group="noOfLines" />
            <log message="Split Group Body: ${body}"/>
                <to uri="bean:extractHeader" />
                <to id="acceptedFileType" ref="predixConsumer" /> 
            </split>
            <to uri="bean:extractHeader?method=cleanHeader"/>
        </when>
        <otherwise>  
            <log message="${file:name} is an unknown file type, sending to unhandled repo." loggingLevel="INFO" />
            <to uri="{{unhandledArchive}}" />
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
</route>
```

...
 and noOfLines is a property

now there is an order to all this as I found out while doing this also. 
please go to the link below for the Camel ordering of components in XML DSL

[Camel DataFormat Jackson using blueprint XML DSL throws context exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50109617/camel-dataformat-jackson-using-blueprint-xml-dsl-throws-context-exception)